# Execute commands in elevation powershell

Tags: node.js, powershell

I am running a Node.JS app that is executing some powershell commands to set the DNS services for my WiFi interface.

Unfortunately, the script fails without admin permissions, so I am trying to elevate the script within node.js

```
Start-Process -FilePath powershell.exe -ArgumentList {
   Write-Host "Hello"
   Set-DnsClientServerAddress -InterfaceIndex 10 -ServerAddresses ("127.0.0.1", "8.8.8.8")
   sleep 5
} -verb RunAs
```

For some reason, this isn't applying the changes, despite the script outputting "hello" and waiting for 5 seconds. Does anyone know why that might be?

Comment: Add `-PassThru` to the `Set-DnsClientServerAddress` and check the status output for the interface.

Comment: Double-check you've still got the right `InterfaceIndex` (anectodally, my PC behaves strangely with a vpn pseudo-interface). Add `-Verbose` to `Set-DnsClientServerAddress` as well and see if it adds any useful output.

Comment: @Zilog80 it logs the old server addresses

Comment: @Cpt.Whale `VERBOSE: Microsoft DNS Client settings will be changed as requested. This will affect name resolutions on the adapter "WiFi"` logs that, however it still doesn't change. I have double checked the right interface index

Comment: It sounds like it's running, maybe try `-ServerAddresses 127.0.0.1,8.8.8.8` instead without quotes or parentheses. Do you set the dns settings back to what they were anywhere in your script?